# Why is state changing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't understand why the state in the following action is changed, even if the dispatch() function is not called. Even when response.errors is full, the state is changed.

PS : state seems to be updated at the end of the map function.

```
export function updateHierarchies(){
 return function(dispatch, getState){
   let hierarchies = getState().hierarchies.hierarchies
   let hierarchyToEdit = getState().hierarchies.hierarchyToEdit
   let hierarchiesToUpdate = hierarchies[`level_${hierarchyToEdit.level}`].hierarchies

   hierarchiesToUpdate.map(function(hierarchy, index) {
     if(hierarchy.id === hierarchyToEdit.id){
       hierarchiesToUpdate[index] = hierarchyToEdit
     }
   });

   let newHierarchies = hierarchies
   newHierarchies[`level_${hierarchyToEdit.level}`].hierarchies = hierarchiesToUpdate

   put("/admin/hierarchies.json", {hierarchy: hierarchyToEdit}).then((response) => {
     console.log(response)
     if(response.errors){
       alert(response.errors);
     } else {
       dispatch(saveHierarchy(newHierarchies));
     }
   })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mutating the stating at this line:

`hierarchiesToUpdate[index] = hierarchyToEdit`

`hierarchiesToUpdate` is a reference to an inner property of your state.

You can prevent it to be a reference by creating a new array with the same values:

```
let hierarchiesToUpdate = [...hierarchies[`level_${hierarchyToEdit.level}`].hierarchies]
```

Comment: thanks Diogo! I was aware one should not mutate the state but I thought this would only happen if I did something like hierarchies[index] = hierarchyToEdit. I was not aware of the difference between "reference" and a "copy". This is helpful, thank you.